# Finding $\sum\frac{1}{2^n(n+1)}$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

What is the sum of $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n(n+1)}$$

I've spent an insane amount of time on this problem. I checked on Wolfram and it gives $ln(4)$, which I assume you get from $2\ln(2)$.

I know that the integral of $\frac{1}{n+1}$ is $\ln(n+1)$. What am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: Pls use MathJax!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With integrals:
$$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{2^n(n+1)}=2\sum_{n\geq 0}\int_{0}^{1/2}x^n\,dx = 2\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{dx}{1-x}=2\log 2=\color{red}{\log 4}.$$

Answer (score 4):

We have

$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n(n + 1)} = 2\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(1/2)^{n+1}}{n+1} = -2 \ln\left(1 - \frac{1}{2}\right) = -2\ln \frac{1}{2} = \ln 4$$

using

$$\ln(1 - x) = -\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{x^{n}}{n},\quad |x| < 1.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Use $$\ln (1- x) = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}$$

Comment: Bottom limit is $1$, surely!

Comment: Yup, typo there, thanks!