# Evaluate the infinite sum of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^n(n+1)}$

Tags: calculus, power-series

Would someone be able to show which well-known power series works with this? And help evaluate it? The sum is  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^n(n+1)}$.

Comment: Is that what you wanted?

Comment: @Gary Yep! Thanks, what was the issue?

Comment: The `^` at the end

Comment: Do you know the Maclaurin series of $ - \log (1 - x)$ about $x=0$?

Comment: @Gary I'm looking at that series now, and I'm not seeing how it fits in

Comment: Basically this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1195507/

Answer (score 1):

Use the geometric series:

$$ \frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n$$

Now, to get $ \frac{1}{i+1}$ in denominator sum, we can get that factor by integrating both side w.r.t.x

$$ -\ln(1-x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1 } +C$$

Now, we need put $x=\text{something}$ to make this sum match with the one in the question, I'll let you finish the problem.

**Note:** I've used the property that you can interchange integrals and summations in the domain of summation in the integration step.

Comment: More problems of this kind are doable using geometric series . For example [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/48225/688539)

Comment: It should be $x^{n+1}$ in the series for $\log$.

Comment: Good point, have fixed it now

Comment: A direct answer would be to integrate between $0$ and $1/3$.

Comment: Indeed but the point I was trying to show is how problems involving summations can be solved by the application of calculus on the geometric series rather than solving one example

Answer (score 0):

Consider the classic series
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} t^{n} = \frac{1}{1-t} $$
and integrate both sides. This leads to
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{t} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} u^n \, du &= \int_{0}^{t} \frac{du}{1-u} \\
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left[ \frac{u^{n+1}}{n+1} \right]_{0}^{t} &= \left[ - \ln(1-u) \right]_{0}^{t} \\
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1} &= - \ln(1-t)
\end{align}
and finally
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^n}{n+1} = - \frac{\ln(1-t)}{t}. $$

Letting $t$ be a value within the range of convergence gives the desired series.